# The name 'model' does not exist in current context in ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

Here I have added the view IN ASP.NET Core 3.1 project and tried to bind the model but model is not binding at`@model Emp.Models.Employee` and throws an error saying 

`The name 'model' does not exist in current context`. 

Any help will be great

[image]

Comment: If you create a new MVC project, does some issue occur?

Comment: Is this a razor page or MVC view? are you missing the @page directive at the start of your page?